# Tab Style Icon from sObjectType

Tags: describesobject, dynamic-style

Is it possible to get the tab style from the sObjectType?  In other words, if I have an object with a tab icon of "People", the tab style I'd want to return is "Custom15"...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are ways to get to this data, depending on the context.

### Page

```
<apex:page standardController="People__c" tabStyle="People__Tab" ...
```

### Apex Code

Call [Schema.describeTabs()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describeTabs.htm).

### API

Just call [`binding.describeTabs()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describetabs_describetabsetresult.htm) from your application. The documentation includes examples in Java and C#.

Comment: You can also use the describeTab feature in native Apex now, no need to import the Partner WSDL, http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describetabs_describetabsetresult.htm#topic-title

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Thanks for that. I somehow missed that in the documentation. Google is still indexing all the old answers about using the WSDL, and that was that last I'd knew of it, too. Time to re-read the manual again!

Comment: I'm intrigued by your Apex Code section.  I am trying to recreate the relatedList functionality with a bunch of other features built in (user can sort, filter, export, customize columns, etc).  I have a cosmetic desire to replicate the object-related icons as are present natively, but it's not a show-stopper...  I've never used wsdl2apex, I'll give that a shot...

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Also, you linked to the wrong docs in your comment, but I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NathanWilliams You can replicate the icons just by using the "tabStyle" attribute on the `apex:pageBlock`. No need to get fancy.

Comment: That's true, but I am trying to not use the `apex:pageBlock` because I don't like the way the header looks (too much vertical height) and I'm trying to replicate the look of a related list more (much tighter look-and-feel)...  Any ideas?

Comment: @NathanWilliams In that case, you can describe them in Apex Code, like Andrew mentioned; I'd store the icon URL in a variable or wrapper object.

Comment: @sfdcfox I did try that, tho it looks like it only returns the active/showing tabs (not the available/hidden tabs), which is a downside.  Anyway you know of to get around that?

Comment: @NathanWilliams You're right; I've missed that in the docs. Looks like you might need a metadata capture tool, such as found on the AppeXchange (I forget the name, but it's free).